# Eclipse automatically removes lines from .properties file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, properties-file

I have few .properties files for my Spring project containing key value pair. At a particular line, when I add some content, and close the file, some of the newly added lines are getting deleted automatically.

For example, in the below, I added my lines after HALSTCD=State.

```
HALPHONENBR=Phone (optional) 
RECPEMAIL=Email notifications
HALSTCD=State

######################### Field Mapping For POS Information #################### 
WSCACCT=WSC Account#
WSC_PSTLCD=WSC Postal Code
POSNONTRANS=POS Non-Trans IDs


##################### Field Mapping For TD/IPD/NAFTA Information ################
SCAC=Standard Carrier Abbreviation Code
```

After saving the file, closing it and when I reopen again, some of the lines are getting deleted.

```
HALPHONENBR=Phone (optional) 
RECPEMAIL=Email notifications
HALSTCD=State
WSC_PSTLCD=PSTLCD POSD
POSNONTRANS=POS Non-Trans IDs


##################### Field Mapping For TD/IPD/NAFTA Information ################
SCAC=Standard Carrier Abbreviation Code
```

Please tell me how to prevent this from happening. I'm using Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because I was repeating the same key twice in the same file and eclipse automatically deletes them every time I closed and re-opened again. I removed multiple occurrence of keys and it worked fine.